# Is there any way to control settings inside iphone app rather than settings outside the app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any way to control settings inside iphone app rather than settings outside the app?

and

I could not find what kind of item I will add to plist in settings.bundle in order to change font type for example; Times New Roman to Calibri

I searched other references that people gave me 1 day ago but I could not find a point that makes this subject clear.

Answer (score 1):

yes, but you have to build your own UI if you want to let the users edit them.

Comment: I want to control three setting items : font size, type, and a background color of text view. How will I achieve this ? (build my UI)
do u have any link or reference how to achieve this?

Comment: you may check the UICatalog http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html sample to get start on what controls are available. then you'd need to know how to link screen elements (probably via Interface Builder) to an attribute (IBOutlet)... probably it can not be covered in one single SO question